# How to add comment at generated report at Excel format?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

Is possible in a report made with Jasper Studio add some comments to column header cells?

Those comments sholud be exportable in excel format.

The request is to add some comments in an excel report made with Jasper (like the red triangle in excel when add a comment to a cell).

I've tried with hyperlink with no results.

Comment: AIK, it is not possible using JasperReports out of the box. You can try to create your own exporter on Java. Or you can add comment using Apache POI (as post action) after getting result with help of JasperReports. [How to add Cell Comments to Excel sheet using POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7153254/876298)

Comment: Tnx! I'm trying to find a workarond for the comment "section"..
Do you know if is possible to hide a row when exporting to excel from hasper serve?
I've thought to make a first raw with all the comments and hide it when exports to excel in order to have only the column header row visible..